# Unable to make HTTP Post request using elixir?

Tags: http, elixir

The code i am trying with is:-

```
response = HTTPotion.post(url, [body: "{channel: \"#bot\", username: \"watson\", text: \"test\"}"])
```

The response i am getting is:-

```
%HTTPotion.Response{body: "invalid_payload",......, status_code: 400}
```

Comment: You did a post request and it returned. The problem is that the server responds with "bad request". You probably need to send something else to your server and it is not a problem with elixir, but the message content.

Comment: This is the sample curl request which works:-
curl -X POST url -d '{"channel": "bot", "username": "ab", "text": "test"}'

Comment: All i want to know is know to send the data params in the request

Comment: In your request `channel`, `username` and `text` are surrounded with quotes. Try the same thing in your Elixir code. This probably prevented server from parsing the request correctly.

Comment: Yes, it's working that way. Now, the another problem i am facing is that  I am unable to get the variables inside the body. eg:- #bot, i want to take from a variable

Comment: Is the URL you're trying to post to – public? If so, share it please, it will make helping you easier

Comment: No, the url is internal. Now i can make post request with status code 200. Only problem is how to take a variable inside body? eg:- i want to take "#bot", as some variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a successful request, but the body was wrong. In JSON there should be quotes around the field names:

```
[body: "{\"channel\": \"#{bot}\", \"username\": \"watson\", \"text\": \"test\"}"]
```

Also the syntax for string interpolation is `#{variable_name}` for example:

```
iex(1)> bot = "mybot"
iex(2)> "#{bot}"
```

Manually encoding JSON is error prone so you probably want to use `Poison`.

```
iex(3)> Poison.encode!(%{bot: bot, username: "watson", text: "test"})
"{\"username\":\"watson\",\"text\":\"test\",\"bot\":\"mybot\"}"
```